# PHP Fetch Present Week data From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

The below PHP code is working fine for the present date to fetch data from MySQL for attendance of a particular id defined. I need it to fetch for the present week and month. I have Googled a lot but unable to solve. Small help will be appreciated a lot.

In case if there is a possible way with JavaScript also please let me know.

```
// SELECT Time Zone
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Belfast");

// SELECT Date With Default Time i.e  "00:00:00"

$date= date("y-m-d 00:00:00");

$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','Uid','PASS','DB');  

//Passed From Ajax      
$Fetch_date = $_POST['ID'];

// Example Date is 2015-06-18 00:00:00 And id is 12345
$query ="SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE  RegID='$Fetch_date' And Date='$date' ";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   //Echo result hear Working Fine
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This month:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00');
$date2 = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('last day of this month'));

$sql = "select * from attendance where RegID='$Fetch_date' and Date > '$date1' and Date < '$date2' ";
```

This week:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('monday this week'));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('sunday this week'));

$sql = "select * from attendance where RegID='$Fetch_date' and Date > '$date1' and Date < '$date2' ";
```

P.S.: This question has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: It is throwing the error as below                                                       Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\working-DONOT-TOUCH\graph.php on line 15

Comment: change `die(mysqli_error())` to `die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` (put the mysqli link as first parameter) and paste the error thrown

Comment: the first line of code seems to have a typo error near date('Y-m-1 ?

Comment: no, that is a valid syntax even in php 4. I changed it to `Y-m-01`, however.

Comment: @mariobgr the weakly one is fetching based on month Thnx For the help at least getting something Plz help me on that

Comment: I did not really get that - "the weakly one is fetching based on month" ?

Comment: hey Shaik, week not weak, they are not the same, I have revised your Q a while ago for grammar, capitalization and everything, don't mess it up again.

Comment: @mariobgr, 1) The php query for month is working perfectly..no issues with that. 2) What i need now is, the weekly PHP query is fetching information of all values of the present month, However what i need is, if today is 8th June 2015, i need this query to consider that 8th June is the first day of the week and hence it should show the values of that particular day and noting else, however the query you gave is fetching values of the present month. another example: If i run this query on 9th June 2015, the query should return only data of 8th June and 9th June of this week and noting else.

Comment: I edited the answer a while ago to `monday this week`, which should be returning the correct date. Maybe you were viewing an outdated version of the answer.

Comment: @mariobgr, the PHP script for week worked perfectly fine. however i think i need a small change in the script. Your script reads all the values in between Monday 00:00:00 and Sunday 23:59:59. In the process or reading the values, the script does not ready the values which have an entry with time 00:00:00, it reads everything in the range "00:00:01 -  23:59:58", but it skips the data with value 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. Reason we need this is because, the conjob in the database runs exactly at 00:00:00 and we need this PHP able to read them too.

Comment: Then change the SQL to `where RegID='$Fetch_date' and Date >= '$date1' and Date <= '$date2'`

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [mysql-date-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear):

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM attendance 
                  WHERE  RegID = '$Fetch_date' 
                  AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
                  AND MONTH(Date) = MONTH(NOW()) 
                  AND WEEKOFYEAR(Date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())";
```

In Javascript you may test it the similar way,
 use [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) and [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). A function which returns the Week of the year is not available , but may use comparision based on `Math.floor(MillisecondsOfTheDate/MillisecondsOfAWeek)`

Comment: wait, btw, he was asking for the current month, not the current year

Comment: He was asking for the present week, the comparison of the year is needed to exclude results with the same WEEKOFYEAR but in another year.

Comment: I see now that  he was asking for  the month too, I've edited the query